# Need help to identify this IC

Tags: power-electronics, identification, buck

I am struggling for about three days now to find the part number for U118. Tried every online database, but I still cannot figure it out. Marking is **14YN/H 891 A981**.

Any ideas about which manufacturer uses this format?

[image]

The chip in question is a buck regulator in a DFN-8 2x2mm package, pins 1-2 are VIN, and 7-8 are SW. VIN is 5V, VOUT not measured as U118 is now toasted. The board is manufactured by a South Korean supplier, and the part in question sits on the cheaper spectrum. They previously used a dual buck regulator (ADP5034) and changed to this obscure one for the mass-produced version.

Found one part from Renesas which matches the package but the pinout is not applicable.

After de-soldering:

[image: U118 de-soldered]

[Edited] Clarification regarding pinout of identified ICs so far

[Edited] Added picture after de-soldering

Comment: Depending on the configuration, it might not be a case of 2x VIN pins but VIN and EN.  I can't see the traces on the other side of the chip, but it also might be a case of SW and FB pins instead of 2x SW.  If there's no voltage divider for FB, the DC resistance of the inductor might be low enough to give a positive continuity reading between FB and SW.

Comment: A few questions:    What is/are the ground pins? Is there an EP? Where is the FB pin?

Comment: Did you check with continuity test if Vout goes to 3.3 or some core voltage rail? Would help a bit. Are there explicit GND pins or is only the power pad on GND? Please try to get a sharper image so we can see which nearby components are wired to the chip (coil, resistor R119, some capacitors) @vir: good hints!

Comment: @vir great points. Thanks. After de-soldering U118, the SW/PULSE or SW+FB pads do not give a continuity reading to GND, which has led me to believe that this happened inside the broken chip.

Comment: @Jarrett PAD is the only GND that I had identified so far.

Comment: @datenheim will post photo of it after de-soldering if you think it helps in identifying this chip. C113, C114, D101, R119, and the inductor are definitely part of the power block and the layout appears to be based on some manual/reference design.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the PCB? In which product was it? Maybe the brand?

Comment: @ArthurChassande it is the U300 board from the kit below, the USB2MIPI converter board which uses the CYUSB3065 chip from Cypress Semiconductor. Reference designs for this chip do feature the same inductor and diode, but the regulator (U118) they used is different. https://ro.mouser.com/ProductDetail/meerecompany/SD-H60NB-1A8

Comment: Pin #5 is also GND.

Comment: Working link - https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/meerecompany/SD-H60NB-1A8?qs=iLbezkQI%252BsiD%2FOkKPiV%2FBw%3D%3D

Comment: Where does Vout go? If it is connected to VCC of some chips we could encircle the output voltage value a bit.

Comment: Thanks fzabkar from EEVblog forums for discovering that the part is TPS22975NDSGT, a fancy load switch from TI. The transformer in the picture is a common mode choke, likely DLW5BTM102SQ2. The diode is there for ESD protection. Replacing U118 with a 0 ohm resistor makes the board functional again, confirming that the load switch failed by shorting itself to GND. https://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/need-help-to-identify-this-ic/msg4605931/#msg4605931